# Why does Scala compiler fail with “Cannot resolve reference reduceByKeyAndWindow with such signature”?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I've got the following line in my Spark Streaming application that compiles fine:

```
val kafkaDirectStream: InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String,String]] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...)
kafkaDirectStream.map(_ => ("mockkey", 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_+_, Seconds(30))
```

When I use the variant of `reduceByKeyAndWindow` with two `Duration`s as follows:

```
.reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(30), Seconds(10))
```

I face the below compiler error:

> Cannot resolve reference reduceByKeyAndWindow with such signature

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `kafkaDirectStream.map(_ => ("mockkey", 1))`, you'll have `DStream[(String, Int)]` (which you can read about in the official documentation at [org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)).

It appears that implicit scope does not give enough knowledge about types and hence the error:

> missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$3, x$4) => x$3.$plus(x$4))

Unfortunatelly, I can't really explain what the root cause of the compilation error is, but a solution is to define a method or function with the types specified explicitly and use it instead (not underscores alone, i.e. `_ + _`).

```
val add: (Int, Int) => Int = _ + _
// or def add(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
mapped.reduceByKeyAndWindow(add, Seconds(30), Seconds(10))
```

That will pass the Scala compiler.

(wish I knew if there's a better solution somehow helping the Scala type inferencer).